# How to animate Horizontally/LeftToRight?

Tags: ios, animation

I have no problem animating vertically but what would I have to do to the values to animate horizontally? Even the built in animations in apple's guidelines don't provide any reference for horizontal animations. Just cover vertically. Coding for iOS in XCode 5 with Objective-C. Thanks!

```
        - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        if (textField == self.passwordTextField) {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
            [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y - 40), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.passwordTextField) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y + 40), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: you are adjusting the frame's origin y value, try changing its x value...

Comment: Replace your self.view.frame.origin.x with (self.view.frame.origin.x + 40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(
    self.view.frame.origin.x - 20,
    self.view.frame.origin.y - 40,
    self.view.frame.size.width, 
    self.view.frame.size.height
);
```

Then, you will be moving on X 20 pixels to the left